# How to prevent OSX popup for incoming connections for Python app?

Tags: macos, python-3.x

I am developing a simple python3 server app. I invoke it like this:

python3 bbserver.py

Each time after doing this I get the OSX popup:

Do you want the application “Python.app” to accept incoming network connections?

I've tried making an exception for python3 executable (there is no python3.app) in the firewall and have tried code signing with a codesign certificate thus:

codesign -f -s mycodecert /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3 --deep

No luck.

Comment: Maybe you have to make it a standalone application if you want to exclude it.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about that. Does that mean I need to reconvert to standalone each time I make an edit?

Comment: I never tried, but I think you can edit the source file inside the app.

Comment: Any updates on this? I am really interested about this and I don't really want to disable the Firewall prompts completely in order not to be annoyed by unittests executions.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a virtualenv or anything similar you could be signing the wrong version of python.

```
sudo codesign --force --deep --sign - $(which python)
```

To check the status of the certificate that was used to sign an app:

```
codesign -dv /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3
codesign -dv $(which python)
```

Example Unsigned:

```
hostname ~ $ codesign -dv $(which python)
/usr/local/bin/python: code object is not signed at all
```

Example Signed:

```
hostname ~ $ workon py27
(py27)hostname ~/py27 $ codesign -dv $(which python)
Executable=/Users/me/.virtualenvs/py27/bin/python
Identifier=python-555549446408a33553ca3f479122ce9278a9a269
Format=Mach-O universal (i386 x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=196 flags=0x2(adhoc) hashes=3+2 location=embedded
Signature=adhoc
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=136
```

Comment: After codesigning the python executable, I _still_ get the popup almost every time. `$(which python)` returns a symlink inside the venv directory, and I also signed the executable it points to. `codesign -dv` on it shows the signature. Any idea what the issue can be?

Comment: I tried invoking the exe name instead of the symlink, which seemed to make the popup rarer. But then sometimes it crops up again.

Answer (score 0):

For Anaconda users who have updated to Mojave, you may be running an outdated/unsigned version of Python.

Simply run `conda upgrade conda` to update Python to the latest version, which should also be signed, and the problem should go away. If it doesn't, then you may need to contact Anaconda's support to get them to build a signed package.

Of course, you will also have to `conda upgrade python` for each conda environment you have.